# Construction Issue with two Planning Entities

Tags: optaplanner

I am trying to implement a FlowShop. I got an amount of different Jobs i need to schedule. My Jobs exist all of the same amount of operations and operations can be processed on certain machines. Most can be processed by only one machine, but there exists one operation where two different machines can handle the processing of it.

So i need to schedule, which machine processes which operation and the sequence of the different jobs.
My first approach was to give every operation a Position in the sequence and all operations of a job had the same Position. But when the solver changed the Position of an operation, the Position of the other operations of the same job havnt changed and i wasnt able to fix that.
So i decided to add a second Planning Entity, Job. Operations of the same Job reference to the same job object. But now i got two Planning Entities (Job and Operation) and i am always getting an Exception, which i dont know how to handle.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The config (QueuedEntityPlacerConfig(null, null)) has no entityClass (null) configured and because there are multiple in the entityClassSet ([class ProductionPlan.domain.Operation, class ProductionPlan.domain.Task]), it can not be deduced automatically.
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.AbstractConfig.deduceEntityDescriptor(AbstractConfig.java:63)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.constructionheuristic.placer.QueuedEntityPlacerConfig.buildEntitySelectorConfig(QueuedEntityPlacerConfig.java:144)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.constructionheuristic.placer.QueuedEntityPlacerConfig.buildEntityPlacer(QueuedEntityPlacerConfig.java:107)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.constructionheuristic.placer.QueuedEntityPlacerConfig.buildEntityPlacer(QueuedEntityPlacerConfig.java:42)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.constructionheuristic.ConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig.buildPhase(ConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig.java:200)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.constructionheuristic.ConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig.buildPhase(ConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig.java:52)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.buildPhaseList(SolverConfig.java:668)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.buildSolver(SolverConfig.java:539)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolverFactory.buildSolver(DefaultSolverFactory.java:49)
    at ScheduleAppLocalSearch.main(ScheduleAppLocalSearch.java:14)
```

If anyone could help me, how to get rid of that Exception i would be really pleased

Addition:
I now added an advanced Configuration, but the Exception is still there

```
<constructionHeuristic>
    <entitySorterManner>NONE</entitySorterManner>
    <valueSorterManner>NONE</valueSorterManner>
      <queuedEntityPlacer>
        <entitySelector id="TaskEntitySelector">
          <cacheType>PHASE</cacheType>
          <entityClass>ProductionPlan.domain.Task</entityClass>
        </entitySelector>
        <changeMoveSelector>
          <entitySelector mimicSelectorRef="TaskEntitySelector"/>
        </changeMoveSelector>
      </queuedEntityPlacer>
    </constructionHeuristic>
  <constructionHeuristic>
    <entitySorterManner>NONE</entitySorterManner>
    <valueSorterManner>NONE</valueSorterManner>
    <queuedEntityPlacer>
      <entitySelector id="OperationEntitySelector">
        <cacheType>PHASE</cacheType>
        <entityClass>ProductionPlan.domain.Operation</entityClass>
      </entitySelector>
      <changeMoveSelector>
        <entitySelector mimicSelectorRef="OperationEntitySelector"/>
      </changeMoveSelector>
    </queuedEntityPlacer>
  </constructionHeuristic>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Construction Heuristic with 2 planning entity classes needs [an advanced configuration](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#allocateEntityFromQueue).

Comment: i read this part of the documentation and i found another post about this Problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55145202/no-entityclass-and-because-there-are-multiple-in-the-entityclassset-it-can-not). I added the advanced config to my question above due to size. 
But i am still getting exactly the same Exception and i have no idea what to do.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same exception? I doubt the stacktrace is exactly the same.

Comment: Actually its exactly the same. I dont know why. But should i have added anything else then the construction heuristic part i posted above? And i dont understand what this <entitySelector id="TaskEntitySelector"> actually means. Should i have added something anywhere with the name TaskEntitySelector?

Comment: I found a solution which works for now. I changed the Relationship between the Jobs and the Operations. Now the Job has a List of Operations, instead of the Operation has a Job Attribute, and i had to change the getter/setter for the OperationList in the PlanningSolution.  Then i added the advanced Configuration from above and for now i am getting the Output i wanted. It doesnt looks like its the fastest Solution possible but as long as it works its fine for me.
If you have an idea why the other approach didnt worked let me know. Thanks for your help.